# Calling a javascript function from C++

Tags: javascript, c++

I want to call a Javascript function from C++ code.

Following is my Javascript code  (hello.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    alert("hello");
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myFunction(); 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Say I have C++ code as following

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 // Calling the Javascript function  [ myFunction() ] here 
}
```

I have a gateway device running Ubuntu 10.04 and I cannot do any new software installation on the device.

I tried using nodejs and emscriptem to call the javascript function from C++. To use the nodejs and emscriptem 
methods I need to do apt-get update ,install SDKs etc on the gateway device which is not allowed.

So is there any other way that I can call a javascript function from C++  apart from nodejs and emscriptem ?

Comment: You want to execute the C++ code server-side and the JavaScript code client-side?

Comment: No both are on the client side  and client is running Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: Is it possible for you to use the qt toolkit? Because it contains functions to do just this.

Comment: And is the HTML page containing your JavaScript already running in a browser? Do you need to start it if not?

Comment: You may be looking for what's called a headless browser.

Comment: actually I cannot use QT because QT libraries wont get loaded in the gateway device which is running Ubuntu . Again I cannot install or update any packages in the device

Comment: @CompuChip I am already running the html page. Now whenever the C++ code is executed the output "hello" should pop up

Comment: In order for QT to work, you only need to install it on the machine where you compile your code (which can be linux). On the ubuntu machine where you run it, you only need to have the libraries, which you can ship with your executable...

Comment: Could I ask what the broader picture is? I can't think of many situations where trying to run JavaScript through C++ would be beneficial to just doing whatever you need to do either via just JavaScript/HTML or C++

Comment: @Moby : Actually I have a C++ code which will continue to monitor the size of a SQlite database in the device . If the size of the SQlite database is more than 90% the C++ code should send a message or data to the javascript and the Java script will show the user a pop up that database is almost filled. This is the whole requirement actually . So I just want to send a message to javascript using a simple function call

Comment: @DrDonut : Sir actually the code is getting compiled using g++ in the gateway not in the Desktop PC. Also qmake is not installed in the gateway device

Comment: @Stupidto, sorry, did see that :) Good luck!

Comment: @Moby : Sir actually the code is a simple code used to collect data from the database and the pop up should be shown to the user who is connecting to the gateway device and opening the HTML page using IP configured in the gateway not in the firmware code. So I wont be able to create a pop up in the firmware C++ code

Comment: Ah @Sudipto, so the application and the JavaScript will be run on separate machines?

Comment: @Moby : Actually both are in the same machine . i.e., the gateway device. So actually is there any way other than nodejs and emscriptem to call the js function ?

Comment: I see, when you mentioned a desktop PC, I had interpreted this as a client who was connected to the device, sorry. As a simple solution, I would suggest then, using something like the `system` function to run a third piece of software - you could set it up to run the browser on the machine for example, including the name of your html file as one of the commandline parameters - would you see any technical issues if you were to do this?

Comment: @Moby : By system function do you mean the commands of the Linux ? if yes how can that help ?

Comment: I have written a longer post as an answer below which will hopefully clarify what I mean

Comment: Thanks a  lot for your support

Answer (score 1):

There is my way to comunicate a C++ code with a page in the same machine. **No system calls, no external libs. Just standard javascript and C++.** The trick is that C++ code generates a js that calls the function and then the page periodically loads the js to run the function.

The C++ code

```
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;

int call_id = 0;
//the function that commit an update
void callFunction() {
  // the file to write the response
  ofstream fout("response.js");
  //this file just call javascript function with a correlative
  //see the page for the definition of caller function
  fout << "caller(" << call_id++ << ", myFunction);"; 
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  //a dummy loop to generate different updates
  while ( true ) {
    sleep(2);
    if ( std::rand()%2 )
      callFunction();
  };
}
```

The page

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<script type="application/javascript">
//this code is needed to prevent repeated calls. It checks a correlative to each function call to not repeat it
var call_id = 0;

function caller(i, func) {
  if ( call_id < i ) {
   call_id = i;
   func();
  }
}

//your function
function myFunction() {
  alert("my Function called");
 }

//this code load an js script and prevents infinite spamming of script elements
function loadScript(file) {
  var id = "some_script_id";
  var e = document.getElementById(id);
  if ( e != null )
    e.parentNode.removeChild(e);
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.id = id;
  script.src = file;
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

//to update
window.setInterval(function(){
  //replace with the path where the c++ code write the response 
  loadScript("file:///path/to/response.js"); 
}, 1000);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering your limitations, you can either write a rather complicated piece of server software in C++ with a companion JavaScript that will keep running in an open browser window and poll a socket on the server (i.e. your C++ program).

Alternatively, a very easy but rather ugly way of achieving this will be to just call the browser through the `system` function in C++, running the script upon execution, e.g.

```
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char argv[])
{
    // Code to retrieve database results

    // Code to generate HTML/JavaScript file - if relevant - saving to /path/script.html

    // Run the browser with your script loaded
    system("firefox -browser -url /path/script.html");

    return 0;
}
```